# dashboard to display 2 text values

Tags: apex, visualforce, dashboard

Is there a way to create a dashboard that has the format :

```
Region             Status (Rich text) 
North America      pending
Japan              o Yet to be approved
                   o Waiting for approval
```

I tried to use a tabular report as source by limiting the rows but I do not have a value (a number, boolean etc..)

I switched to matrix/summary but I am able to display only a record count

Is there a easy solution to just display 2 texts in the dashboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know - not without counter / other numeric.

If you can live with having a numeric column like that - it's pretty easy

[image: final product]

Create a new summary report, group by your 2 "factors". Add a chart to this report (I've used standard bar chart) and make sure the subgroup is represented on the chart (stacked, split, whatever. but it has to be there).

[image: report chart]

And then you need to explicitly select columns you want in the dashboard chart

[image: dashboard component details]

It won't save without "column 3" with numeric so I guess that's it...

Comment: The only issue i hve wth this approach is that i still have to limit the rows , and having a rich text makes it harder because scroll bars do not appear on the dashbpard as the richtext gets bigger, this is a good solution but i think i woll create a vf page and yse a visualforce component :). This way i can use css and show a scrollbar

Comment: I'd say a RTF in a dashboard smells suspicious ;) But yeah, I'm afraid you have to go VF in that case.